# Crystal Reports: Define preset parameters based on report user

Tags: crystal-reports

Different users of the same report look at different parameters. For example, user 1 will look at billings A, B, and C. User 2 might look at A, C, D, E, F, G, and so on.

Is there a way in crystal reports for the user to enter their name, for example, and get their parameters preset?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option in Crystal but there's at least one 3rd-party viewer that supports this type of functionality by allowing users to save and reuse named parameter sets. See list of 3rd-party viewers [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers).

Alternatively, you could create just a single parameter that asks for name and then use record selection logic that branches according to that choice.

Comment: I was thinking about the alternative you specified. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I was thinking maybe some sort of IF USER A THEN {?BILLING CODE} = {1, 2, 3} as a formula field, and then connect that formula field to the Record Select Expert, rather than the {?BILLING CODE} directly to the Record Select Expert.

Tried that, but it didn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Looked into it again and think I figured it out. I like the record selection logic idea. Will try to go with that. Didn't know about 3rd party viewers. Thanks!